# How to know if jQuery validator already exists for a form?

Tags: forms, jquery-validate, tooltip

Imagine I have an unordered list with 2 cols, col 1 is the name of a file and col 2 is a pencil icon which has tooltip enabled.  When the user clicks on this pencil icon, it opens a tooltip which contains a form.  In this form the user will enter a new file and the value will be validated.

When the tooltip is shown, I attach jQuery validator to the form inside the tooltip.  The problem is that each time the tooltip is shown, a new validator is attached. I would like to only attach one validator to a form.  How can I successfully check if validator already exists for a form?

```
var validator = forms.validate();
console.log(validator);

// always evaluate to true
if (validator) {

}
```

This doesn't seem to work.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The `.validate()` method is for ***initializing*** the plugin and only gets called ***once***.  The `.valid()` method is used for ***testing*** the validity of a single form element or of the entire form.  [Please refer to documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org).

Comment: In other words, you should not be reinitializing the plugin every time a pencil icon is clicked and a form opens up. All forms on the page should be attached to the `.validate()` method ***once*** on page load. Then they are always ready to be validated no matter how many times you click on a particular pencil.   And you would never need to check if the validator exists... because you'll know it already exists.

Comment: I can't attach validator to every form before the page loads, since some forms will be created on the fly.

Comment: Then you would attach `.validate()` immediately after you create the form.  It does not hurt anything if this happens more than once... the plugin automatically ignores any subsequent calls.

Comment: FYI: I do not understand what you are doing... it is literally impossible to attach multiple validators to a single form because the plugin does not allow it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the jQuery data to check if the validator exists on a form element like this:

```
var form = $('#myform');
if(form.data('validator')){
    // validator exists     
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I realized that I could just check to see if a form has the class "novalidate" to determine if the form has a validator attached or not.

```
var forms = jQuery("form.edit");

if (forms.attr("novalidate")) {
   return;
}
```